# Interrupt configuration for touchscreen MXT224E in imx6DL android kitkat

Tags: android, linux, embedded, embedded-linux, interrupt

I am interfacing Atmel MXT224E touchscreen with imx6DL Processor in Android Kitkat 4.4.2.

I have connected it to I2C-2 and interrupt pin is used in GPIO_1_8.

I am getting acknowledge from Touchscreen with Family ID, Variant ID and version correctly.

I am facing a problem with interrupts. When I give the command "cat /proc/interrupts" I can see atmel_mxt_ts interrupt but when I touch the screen it is not responding that is I cannot see the interrupt requests increasing when pressing the touchscreen. Can anyone help with this? Does anybody have the documentation for configuring the interrupts in the board file or do I have to make changes in driver file? Thanks in advance.

For this problem any configuration setting we have to do in kernel setting?

Comment: I am having exactly this same problem, did you ever solve it? Please share your experience! FYI, my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376884/how-to-correctly-configure-interrupt-for-int-line-of-atmel-mxt641t-touch-chip-in