# How to correctly configure interrupt for INT line of Atmel MXT641T touch chip in Android 5 kernel device tree?

Tags: android, touch, embedded-linux, atmel, device-tree

I am having troubles getting a touch screen powered by an Atmel MXT641T on an Android 5 platform to work.

The setup I have is as follows:

- Hardware: Inforce 6309 SBC with Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 msm8916 ARM64 processor.
- Custom touch screen with Atmel MXT641T controller chip.
- I2C connection between Atmel and Snapdragon connected to I2C0.
- Android 5 operating system using Linux kernel 3.10 from `git://codeaurora.org/kernel/msm-3.10.git` branch `Rel_V1.3` (this is part of the BSP that comes with the SBC)...
- ... but with the latest version of the Atmel driver `atmel_mxt_ts.c` overlaid on the kernel tree (but also tested with version of `atmel_maxtouch_ts.c` in `msm-3.10.git` which shows same behaviour).
- INT line from Atmel chip connected to GPIO 53 (this is `EXT_CONN_GPIO_1` of this board) and with external pull-up resistor to 1.8V.
- RESET line from Atmel chip disconnected.

What I did to get to this point is to modify the device tree to include the Atmel device as follows:

```
&i2c_0 {

  atmel_maxtouch_ts@4a {
    compatible = "atmel,maxtouch";
    reg = <0x4a>;
    interrupt-parent = <&msm_gpio>;
    interrupts = <53 0>;
    atmel,panel-coords = <0 0 1024 768>;
    atmel,display-coords = <0 0 1024 768>;
    atmel,family-id = <164>;
    atmel,variant-id = <2>;
    atmel,version = <21>;
    atmel,build = <0xaa>;
  };

};
```

For reference, the `msm_gpio` is defined as follows in the BSP (untouched).

```
&soc {
        tlmm_pinmux: pinctrl@1000000 {
                compatible = "qcom,msm-tlmm-8916";
                reg = <0x1000000 0x300000>;
                interrupts = <0 208 0>;

                /*General purpose pins*/
                gp: gp {
                        qcom,num-pins = <122>;
                        #qcom,pin-cells = <1>;
                        msm_gpio: msm_gpio {
                                compatible = "qcom,msm-tlmm-gp";
                                gpio-controller;
                                #gpio-cells = <2>;
                                interrupt-controller;
                                #interrupt-cells = <2>;
                                num_irqs = <122>;
                        };
                };
```

I compiled the kernel as a module (`CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_ATMEL_MXT=m`) and I am running `insmod` manually.

What I see is the following:

- When using the Atmel utility `mxt-app` the device works: when I touch the screen messages come in, so the I2C connection is ok (but it uses polling).
- When loading the driver `mxt_start` is called, in which the interrupt is enabled. I have added a number of debug statements to the driver to verify that it is actually loading.
- When loading the driver the info block is read from the device and brief I2C traffic shows on the oscilloscope. The I2C address is read from the device tree so I am sure that my device tree is loaded.
- The input device is registered as `/dev/input/event6` and can be opened with `cat` (but no messages appear when touching the screen).
- The interrupt is visible in `/proc/interrupts` but never fires (see below).
- Whenever I touch the screen, the INT line from the Atmel chip is pulled low by the chip, but no I2C traffic is visible on the oscilloscope.
- I verified that the interrupt triggering condition (`0x0`, `0x8` or `0x2008` as second element in the interrupt cell in the device tree) does not matter by manually causing highs and lows on the interrupt line: no interrupt is triggered in any event.

Entry in `/proc/interrupts`:

```
 $ cat /proc/interrupts
 ...
 326:          0          0          0          0  msm_tlmm_irq  maxtouch
 ...
```

This is what appears in `dmesg`:

```
<6>[   55.290620] atmel_mxt_ts 0-004a: Family: 164 Variant: 2 Firmware V1.5.AA Objects: 43
<4>[   55.291252] atmel_mxt_ts 0-004a: Enabling RETRIGEN workaround
<6>[   55.365918] atmel_mxt_ts 0-004a: Touchscreen size X1024Y768
<6>[   55.367017] input: Atmel maXTouch Touchscreen as /devices/soc.0/78b6000.i2c/i2c-0/0-004a/input/input6
```

What I understand from reading the driver code in `atmel_mxt_ts.c` is that the driver should trigger on this interrupt line, and then query the device by starting an I2C transfer to read the T5 message, upon which the device will return a list of touches which are then passed on to the operating system. I have not found a datasheet or document properly explaining this, but this is what I suspect based on what I have seen so far.

I have tested the GPIO pin 53 (to which I normally connect the INT line of the Atmel chip) manually by doing the following:

```
$ echo 955 > /sys/class/gpio/export     # 955 because EXP_CONN_GPIO_1 is GPIO pin 53, which has offset 902
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio955/value
```

This value changes when I connect the INT line to V+ or ground, so I am sure that I have to use GPIO 53.

No GPIO for the maxtouch driver is shown in `/sys/kernel/debug/gpio`:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
GPIOs 576-607, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-ssr-smp2p-4-out.19, master-kernel:

GPIOs 608-639, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-ssr-smp2p-4-in.18, slave-kernel:

GPIOs 640-671, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-ssr-smp2p-1-out.13, master-kernel:

GPIOs 672-703, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-ssr-smp2p-1-in.12, slave-kernel:

GPIOs 704-735, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-smp2p-4-out.16, smp2p:

GPIOs 736-767, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-smp2p-4-in.14, smp2p:

GPIOs 768-799, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-smp2p-1-out.10, smp2p:

GPIOs 800-831, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-smp2p-1-in.8, smp2p:

GPIOs 832-863, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-smp2p-7-out.6, smp2p:

GPIOs 864-895, platform/qcom,smp2pgpio-smp2p-7-in.4, smp2p:

GPIOs 896-899, spmi/qpnp-pin-ffffffc031550c00, pm8916-gpio:
 gpio-898 (qcom,hub-reset-gpio ) out hi
 gpio-899 (qcom,sw-sel-gpio    ) in  lo

GPIOs 900-901, spmi/qpnp-pin-ffffffc031550800, pm8916-mpp:

GPIOs 902-1023, platform/1000000.pinctrl, msm_tlmm_gpio:
 gpio-922 (adv7533_hpd_irq_gpio) in  lo
 gpio-923 (led1                ) out lo
 gpio-927 (disp_rst_n          ) in  hi
 gpio-933 (adv7533_irq_gpio    ) in  hi
 gpio-934 (hdmi_lvds           ) in  lo
 gpio-940 (7864900.sdhci cd    ) in  hi
 gpio-1009 (volume_up           ) in  hi
 gpio-1010 (camera_focus        ) in  hi
 gpio-1011 (camera_snapshot     ) in  hi
 gpio-1022 (led2                ) out lo
 gpio-1023 (USB_ID_GPIO         ) in  hi
```

I phrased some specific questions to help solve the puzzle:

- What is the correct way to register the interrupt? I am using `interrupt-parent = <&msm_gpio>;` and `interrupts = <53 0>` to identify the GPIO pin 53 of the Snapdragon. I tested with both `<53 0>` and `<53 8>`.
- I sometimes see people use `0x2008` as second entry in the cell. I think the `0x0008` is to set the interrupt to trigger on LOW level, but what does the 13-th bit do? I tested with both `0x0` and `0x8`, does not make a difference (yet :-)).
- Should I expect an entry in `/sys/kernel/debug/gpio`?
- Are any additional entries in the device tree needed to hook up the maxtouch interrupt to the physical pin?
- Where does the IRQ number `326` in `/proc/interrupts` come from, and is there a way to verify what pin it is linked to?
- Is it possible to configure that the INT line will be pulled up by the Snapdragon, instead of having to use an external pull-up resistor?

Thanks in advance for your help.

*PS: And a tangentially related question: how can I quickly test updates of the device tree without having to wait 20 minutes for all Makefiles to load and the kernel to recompile and then flash the new `boot.img` to the device and reboot? I use the command `make bootimage`.*

Comment: Any update on this issue? Dis you manage to solve it ;) I am also facing a similar issue on Snapdragon 820 board.

Comment: Hi @dheeraj, thanks for reminding me to post the answer. Please see below for the device tree configuration that solved the issue for me, I hope it helps you. If you require additional steps or have further questions, let me know then I will refine the answer if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding out that there is already a more or less working touchscreen definition in the device tree but that the pins are different, I ended up with the following device tree:

```
&i2c_0 {

  atmel_maxtouch_ts@4a {
    compatible = "atmel,maxtouch";
    reg = <0x4a>;
    interrupt-parent = <&msm_gpio>;
    interrupts = <53 0x2008>;
    pinctrl-names = "pmx_ts_active","pmx_ts_suspend","pmx_ts_suspend";
    pinctrl-0 = <&ts_int_active &ts_reset_active>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&ts_int_suspend &ts_reset_suspend>;
    pinctrl-2 = <&ts_release>;
    atmel,irq-gpio = <&msm_gpio 53 0x2008>;
    atmel,reset-gpio = <&msm_gpio 54 0>;
    atmel,panel-coords = <0 0 800 480>;
    atmel,display-coords = <0 0 800 480>;
    atmel,family-id = <164>;
    atmel,variant-id = <2>;
    atmel,version = <21>;
    atmel,build = <0xaa>;
  };

};
```

so, the following lines are different:

```
interrupts = <53 0x2008>;
pinctrl-names = "pmx_ts_active","pmx_ts_suspend","pmx_ts_suspend";
pinctrl-0 = <&ts_int_active &ts_reset_active>;
pinctrl-1 = <&ts_int_suspend &ts_reset_suspend>;
pinctrl-2 = <&ts_release>;
atmel,irq-gpio = <&msm_gpio 53 0x2008>;
atmel,reset-gpio = <&msm_gpio 54 0>;
```

The 0x2008 is needed to make the Snapdragon pull up this interrupt line and trigger on the falling edge.

The pinctrl definitions were already located in `qcom/msm8916-pinctrl.dtsi` that comes with the BSP, however, for my case I had to change pin 12 to 54 and pin 13 to 53:

```
diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/msm8916-pinctrl.dtsi b/arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/msm8916-pinctrl.dtsi
index 204c718..80a2a6d 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/msm8916-pinctrl.dtsi
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/msm8916-pinctrl.dtsi
@@ -30,16 +30,6 @@
                        };
                };

-               atmel-int-pin {
-                       qcom,pins = <&gp 53>;
-                       qcom,num-grp-pins = <1>;
-                       label = "atmel-int-pin";
-                       default {
-                               drive-strength = <0>;
-                               bias-pull-up;
-                       };
-               };
-
                ext-cdc-tlmm-lines {
                        qcom,pins = <&gp 116>, <&gp 112>, <&gp 117>,
                                                <&gp 118>, <&gp 119>;
@@ -1175,7 +1165,7 @@

                /* add pingrp for touchscreen */
                pmx_ts_int_active {
-                       qcom,pins = <&gp 13>;
+                       qcom,pins = <&gp 53>;
                        qcom,pin-func = <0>;
                        qcom,num-grp-pins = <1>;
                        label = "pmx_ts_int_active";
@@ -1187,7 +1177,7 @@
                };

                pmx_ts_int_suspend {
-                       qcom,pins = <&gp 13>;
+                       qcom,pins = <&gp 53>;
                        qcom,pin-func = <0>;
                        qcom,num-grp-pins = <1>;
                        label = "pmx_ts_int_suspend";
@@ -1199,7 +1189,7 @@
                };

                pmx_ts_reset_active {
-                       qcom,pins = <&gp 12>;
+                       qcom,pins = <&gp 54>;
                        qcom,pin-func = <0>;
                        qcom,num-grp-pins = <1>;
                        label = "pmx_ts_reset_active";
@@ -1211,7 +1201,7 @@
                };

                pmx_ts_reset_suspend {
-                       qcom,pins = <&gp 12>;
+                       qcom,pins = <&gp 54>;
                        qcom,pin-func = <0>;
                        qcom,num-grp-pins = <1>;
                        label = "pmx_ts_reset_suspend";
@@ -1223,7 +1213,7 @@
                };

                pmx_ts_release {
-                       qcom,pins = <&gp 13>, <&gp 12>;
+                       qcom,pins = <&gp 53>, <&gp 54>;
                        qcom,num-grp-pins = <2>;
                        label = "pmx_ts_release";
```